# Effort Estimation in Production Support Projects

Tags: estimation

How can we do the effort estimation for Production support projects?
Need to decide count of resources in L1,L2 and L3?

I have 2 projects -

1)Apps with few months of Ticket details 
2)Apps with No Ticket Details

Approach I am planning to take :

1)Case 1:I have ticket details and i have taken weightages related to technical ,application complexity etc. and productivity factor i.e. no of tickets per month that can be solved by L1,L2,L2,%distribution of L1,L2,L3, Average Tickets for L1,L2andL3 and based on that decided on the L1,L2,L3 count

2)Case 2:I have taken the application size i.e. LOC, converted it to Function Point and based on productivity factor decided number of resources, then decided on the some % distribution to L1,L2 and L3.

Comment: I think your question a bit broad, can you share a bit more details about your context? That will help you get a better answer.

Comment: Are these really "projects?" And what is the goal of the estimate?  --Also, you need to define your terms, such as L1-L3, and what "resources" you're trying to plan with.

Comment: I am assuming that LOC is Lines of Code, and L1, L2 and L3 are levels of tech support/escalation?   I think CodeGnome is right, you need to program in some hours to translate your question.....  Interesting problem, just not enough information.

Comment: Support isn't really a project, per se. It's a continuous or repeating process. As written, I'm not sure your question is on-topic, but it could be with some editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at
http://www.davidconsultinggroup.com/media/1083856/sizing-application-maintenance-and-support-activities-20.pdf
And
http://docslide.us/documents/production-support-estimation-whitepaper.html

These papers give some idea on calculation of total effort, then calculate FTE ..And then based on some %, you can distribute between L1,L2 and L3

Comment: Can you share a quick summary of the links you posted?

Comment: Specific WorkPoint Value for the type of Ticket - Simple/Medium/Complex - for Incidents/ServiceRequest/Problem etc...Based on Your Application, calculate total work points..The sum of WP gives the total ‘size’ of the work delivered during the reporting period. Lets say we have productivity baseline of 8 hours per WP. And we have 10 WP. So it will take 80 hours.Now distribute among L1,L2,L3(not given in paper, based on your experience or previous ticket details)On top of it add management effort etc.